# Select elements by id using multiple values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code to hide a div on-click:

```
$(document).on('click',"[id$=3]",function(){
    $('#preview').hide();
});
```

This works just great. However, what i'd like to do is add in multiple criteria to the selector - and i'm brick-walling this. If it's possible i'd like to achieve this in the same statement. The other div I would like to select ends in 5 `[id$=5]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always add another criteria by adding a `,` to your selector, and putting in another selector.

```
$(document).on('click',"[id$=3], [id$=5]",function(){
    $('#preview').hide();
});
```